# Cannot perform pod init on Mac OS X 10.11.5 El Capitan

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am currently trying to install Cocoapods and load Firebase into my Xcode project. I installed Cocoapods correctly by typing sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods (found on another Stack Overflow question, but it seems like all of the cocoapods commands cannot be found. For instance, when I type pod init or even pod install, it does not find the command.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: It looks like the command Pod is not in your Path variable, did you try just doing *sudo gem install cocoapods* as the official documentation suggests?

Comment: Definitely post a screenshot of your error to better help us help you :)

Comment: After turning off System Integrity Protection and reinstalling Cocoa Pods, it works with no problems just like @7vikram7 suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to OSX El Capitan, I needed to turn off System Integrity Protection and reinstall cocoapods in ElCapitan.

To turn off System Integrity Protection, follow below instructions

> 1) Reboot your mac and press “cmd+r” when booting up. This will cause
>   your mac to start in recovery mode.
>
> 2) Then go into utilities > terminal.
>
> 3) Execute the command below:-    csrutil disable
>
> 4) Execute the command below:-    reboot

To reinstall cocoapods on El Capitan, follow below links,

https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3692

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved all of the installation issues!